# Problem with cohomology (I)

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology

I have some doubts regarding cohomology. As title suggests I will ask these one by one.

Let $G$ be a group and $A$ be $G$-module. Let $C^n(G,A)$ denote the set of all maps from $G \times \cdots \times G $ ($n$ times) to $A$. Let $d_n: C^n(G,A) \rightarrow C^{n+1}(G,A)$ be differential. Let $A^{\prime}$ be $G^{\prime}$ module. Let $\lambda_n:C^n(G,A) \rightarrow C^n(G^{\prime}, A^{\prime})$ be homomorphism. Suppose $\lambda_{n+1} d_n=d_n \lambda_n$.

My problem is how the above condition ensures that $\lambda_n$ induces the homomorphism from cohomology $H^n(G,A)$ to $H^n(G^{\prime},A^{\prime})$

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want a map $H^n(G,A)\rightarrow H^{n+1}(G,A)$. You actually get a map from 
$H^n(G,A)=\text{ker }d_{n+1}/\text{im } d_n$ to $H^n(G',A')=\text{ker }d'_{n+1}/\text{im } d'_n$.

Hint for proof: By combining $\lambda_n$ with the projection from $C^n(G',A')\rightarrow H^n(G',A')$ we get a new map $\overline{\lambda}_n$. Now you need to prove that $\text{im }d_n\subseteq \text{ker }\overline{\lambda}_n$.

Comment: yes you are right. I apologize for that. Actually I was thinking about some other thing. I edit that.

Comment: Thanks @Michalis, I have done all the calculation. I think you want me to check $im~d_{n-1} \subseteq Ker~\bar{\lambda_n}$.